# Linux "for" construct in ksh

Tags: ksh

I normally use the for construct in ksh to quickly iterate over a list of files to perform some action on it. It doesn't seem to work in this scenario:

```
The file info looks like: 
$ ls -l tmp.*  
rw------- 1 op general 375 Jul 25 04:09 tmp.zzyhsg4  
...  
so on. Basically a lot of tmp.* files.    

Now when I try  
$ ls -lS | grep 'Jul 25' | grep 'tmp.*' | cut -d' ' -f9 | more  
tmp.zzyhsg4  
..
```

it will print only the file names as expected.
However when I try the below

```
$ for i in `ls -lS | grep 'Jul 25' | grep 'tmp.*' | cut -d' ' -f9`
>do  
>echo $i  
>done
```

This does not print the name of all the files starting with tmp.* which were created on Jul 25 sorted by size. It prints the size column. Interestingly if I replace the f10 by f6 for the cut it will correctly print the month column. It starts to break after f9.

Any ideas ?

Comment: grepping the output of ls is fickle and a bad idea.  That said, does it work for you if instead of backticks on ls you do: ls ... | while read -r i; do echo $i; done ?  Also, try adding a tr -s ' ' after ls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce exactly what you describe, but I have some suggestions to write more reliable commands.

`cut -d' '` separates fields by spaces. If you have two spaces in a row, there's an empty field between them. So if you try with `Aug  1` instead of `Jul 25`, the file name column is shifted by 1. And if you try with files that are more than 6 months old, the (5-character) time is replaced by a space followed by the 4-digit year. Also, depending on your version of `ls` there may be more than one space between some columns. Yet another issue is that some versions of `ls` don't display the `group` column. And then some file names contain spaces. And some file names contain special characters that `ls` may display as `?`. In summary, you can't parse the output of `ls -l` by counting spaces, and you can't even parse the output of `ls -l` by counting whitespace-delimited fields. Just **don't parse the output of ls**.

The standard command for generating lists of names of existing files is `find`. Since you mention Linux, I'll mention options that work with GNU find (the version you get on Linux) but not on other unixes.

Let's start simple: list the files called `tmp.*` in the current directory.

```
find . -name 'tmp.*'
```

We want only the files created on July 25, that's 7 days ago.

```
find . -name 'tmp.*' -daystart -mtime 7
```

This is fragile since it won't work tomorrow. The usual way to specify a precise date is to create files dated at the earliest and latest allowable times and tell `find` to only return files dated between these two.

```
touch -t 201007250000 .earliest
touch -t 201007260000 .latest
find . -name 'tmp.*' -newer .earliest \! -newer .latest
rm .earliest .latest
```

The `find` command explores subdirectories recursively. If you don't want this:

```
find . -name 'tmp.*' -daystart -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mtime 7
```

If you want the files sorted by size:

```
find . -name 'tmp.*' -daystart -mtime 7 -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sort -n -k 1 | cut -f 2-
```

Finally, if you want to operate on the files, **never** use `find` in backticks, the way you used `ls`, because this will fail if the file names contain whitespace or some special characters, because the shell splits the output of `` `command` `` at whitespace and then does globbing on the resulting words. Instead, use the `-exec` option to `find`; the `;` version executes `mycommand` once per file with `{}` replaced by the file name, whereas the `+` version usually invokes `mycommand` only once with `{}` replaced by the list of file names.

```
find . -name 'tmp.*' -daystart -mtime 7 -exec mycommand -myoption {} \;
find . -name 'tmp.*' -daystart -mtime 7 -exec mycommand -myoption {} +
```

Comment: @HeretoLearn: [This information](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is for Bash, but it applies equally to ksh.

Answer (score 1):

To get all files named `tmp.*`, use

```
$ ls -lS tmp.*
```

With the cut you tell to take the space as a delimiter. That will not work properly. The number of spaces between fields is flexible, so you will have a varying number of fields. (between every 2 spaces you will have an empty field)

Better use `find`, which can shape your file list to any form you like:

```
$ find tmp.* -printf "%s %CD %f\\n" | grep "07/25/10" | sort -n
```

(`man find` to also get the date filtering within the `find` command)